# Pycharm is adding extra slash (\) before single quote (')

Tags: python, pycharm, backslash, string-literals

Whenever I try to store single quote, Pycharm is adding two extra slashes.

```
x = '\''
```

or

```
x = "'"
```

For both cases it gives:

```
x = '\\''
```

Though in `print(x)` it doesn't show these extra two slashes but `ast.literal_eval` can't process this. On the other hand, the built-in interpreter doesn't show this weird behavior.

Comment: can you give a bit more of the code needed to reproduce this?

Comment: It's weird that PyCharm does that, but don't despair - AST doesn't look like it can handle either of the prior cases either.

Comment: Just tested on my machine's PyCharm, worked normally; might be able to turn off that somewhere in the settings

Comment: @dazedconfused it shows only in watch window. Though it doesn't affect the code but I am curious why they put this in watch window. It makes reading the variable's value really painful.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, solved it. The problems were somewhere else. Though PyCharm added two extra slashes but AST could handle this. The error was nothing to do with extra slashes. Silly mistake. Thanks everyone.